# Add more entitiy objects to SaveBundle of Breezejs while intercepting Save function using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I wish to create an interceptor which would intercept Save function of Breezejs and would like to create more entity objects and add them into SaveBundle before finally letting it go through to BreezeController's `SaveChanges` function along with other objects.

```
app.factory('changeHistoryInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$timeout', function ($rootScope, $q, $timeout) {
    var deferred = null, //promise to be returned
        rConfig = null, //config to be returned
        historySectionSet = false, 
        rDatacontext = null;

    var Interceptor = {
        request: function (config) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            rConfig = config;

            if (historySectionSet && config.url.contains('SaveChanges') && rDatacontext && rDatacontext.hasChanges()) {
                $timeout(function () {
                  //I wish to create more entity objects and add them into SaveBundle on listening to this event
                  // so that it can be carried to server along with other objects
                  $rootScope.$broadcast('prepareHistory', { currentDate: new Date() });
                }, 5);                                
                return deferred.promise;
            } 
            else
                return config;
        },
        response: function (res) {
            return res;
        },
        goThrough: function () {
            // called from directive's controller on successfully creation of more entity objects
            // how to access SaveBundle and add those created objects in SaveBundle?
            if (deferred) {
                historySectionSet = false;
                deferred.resolve(rConfig);
                deferred = null; rConfig = null;
            }
        },
        setHistorySection: function (setSection, datacontext) {
            historySectionSet = setSection;
            rDatacontext = datacontext;
        }
    }

    return Interceptor;
}]);
```

Is there anyway to access SaveBundle and put more objects into data properties that is passed through to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this would be to use a wrapper class (e.g. a UnitOfWork) around the EntityManager.  The wrapper's own `SaveChanges` method would perform any special manipulations of the entities prior to calling [saveChanges](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges) on the EntityManager.

```
function SaveChanges() {
    // get array of changed entities
    var changes = _entityManager.getChanges();
    // push additional entities onto the array
    addMoreEntities(changes);
    // save it all.  Note we pass the changes as a parameter
    return _entityManager.saveChanges(changes);
}
```

Then your app would use this `SaveChanges` function instead of calling EntityManager.SaveChanges directly.